# babel's active " making problems in math mode

Tags: math-mode, babel, active-characters

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[norsk]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
   ``forkaster hypotesen om at
$P(\text{"mynt"})=0,5$''. 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Giving the following error message:

```
ERROR: Argument of \language@active@arg" has an extra }.

--- TeX said ---
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.15 \end{frame}
```

From the `.log` file:

> I've run across a `}` that doesn't seem to match anything. For
>   example, `\def\a#1{...}` and `\a}` would produce this error. If you
>   simply proceed now, the `\par` that I've just inserted will cause me
>   to report a runaway argument that might be the root of the problem.
>   But if your `}` was spurious, just type `2` and it will go away.

Comment: What's the reason for typing `\text{"mynt"}`, which is wrong to begin with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is described in the [`babel` documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/babel) as a typical error, see section 1.5 on Shorthands.  The problem is caused by the combination `"}`; the solution given is to add an empty pair of braces so you write `"{}}` instead.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[norsk]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  ``forkaster hypotesen om at
  $P(\text{"mynt"{}})=0,5$''. 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

You can improve the spacing of `"m` by writing `"\!m` instead.

[image: Improved spacing]

However, it may well be simpler to use `\qq` from the `textcmds` package for these quotes:

[image: qq sample]

```
\documentclass[norsk]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=norsk]{babel}
\usepackage{textcmds}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \qq{forkaster hypotesen om at
  $P(\text{\qq{mynt}})=0,5$}. 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

See also the `csquotes` package.

Comment: Is there some meaning to use closing before the word?

Comment: I don't understand the question?

Comment: @Sigur The poster shows knowledge of ` ``...' '`, so I guess there is a specific reason to use `"` (I can't get the markdown right :-( )

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen, I asked why do you use `''mynt''` instead of ``mynt''?

Comment: hmm.... because that is what emacs gives me? probably an error ... (I am using auctex)